# GAE Python: Uploaded image loading. How to load image faster?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

```
class ImageHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        a_user = db.get(self.request.get('img_id'))
        if a_user.profile_img:
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'
            self.response.out.write(a_user.profile_img)
        else:
            self.response.out.write("No image")
```

This is quite slow when loading a image. Every time when I reload a page I see the images reloading starting from top of the image and gradually load the whole image (Please let me know if you don't understand what I mean). Should I cache the img_id? but it seems to me that when you use a handler to load an image, it doesn't help for the application to load faster image. Any ideas on how to load image faster? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't use Blobstore https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Using_the_Images_Service_with_the_Blobstore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you still in development? Things will be much slower in the development server, as that only processes one request at a time. The production performance will be much better.

That said, you might be better off using GAE's built-in image hosting. For that, rather than storing the image data in a blobproperty within your model, you upload it directly to the blobstore and reference it with a `BlobReferenceProperty`. Once that's done, you can use [`Image.get_serving_url()`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions#Image_get_serving_url) to get GAE to serve it directly, so it doesn't have to go through your app at all.

Comment: Also if the image is likely to be requested frequently and you don't want to use the Blobstore you can at least cache/store it in memcache (if it's not too big) that also speeds things up.